# How to build documentation for vuejs component?

Tags: vuejs2, documentation

Is there a tool to build documentation for vuejs components in a way similar to what [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/chat#QChatMessage-API) or Vuetify do for their own components? ie: a browseable table with tabs corresponding to prop, slot, methods, events?

Is there anythis similar to what is Sphinx for Python, ie a tool that does introspection of the code to collect info to show?

Searching in google returned a lot of docuemntation ON veujes rather than how to document our vuejs code...

Comment: I use [`vue-styleguidist`](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

From my limited research, I've found this one: https://vuese.org. I haven't tried it though.